# How to open a url in a mac terminal with the mouse

Tags: macos, url, terminal, mouse

Let's say I have Local:   http://localhost:5173/ printed in my terminal.
I see the link is blue.
How do I open it in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press <kbd>command</kbd> and double click on the link